# Get files alocated in a container using a python azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I want to use an Azure function with python triggered by an HTTP request and get some files (CSV) allocated in a container.

I did read a lot of documentation but I'm not sure what is the correct way to do this (get files from a container using HTTP template)

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking about how to create a containerized Azure function written in python.

There are a set of [base images to create v2.0 or v3.0 functions](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-python).

If you are including your CSV files when you build the container, you would  modify a [sample HttpTrigger function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker-python-sample/blob/dev/HttpTrigger/main.py) to read from the local file and generate a string for the `HttpResponse` method.

If your CSV files are located somewhere else, such as in a storage account, you should get the connection string from an environment variable. That way you can avoid building secrets into your container image and reuse the container image in different environments.